# Its possible use List.fold_left to returns a Js.Obj?

Tags: ffi, reason, bucklescript

I'm trying to do this in ReasonML without success.
The problem is that I don't know the object keys.

```js
const items = {
  foo: () => 'ok',
  bar: () => 'ok2'
};

const result = Object.keys(items).reduce((acc, key) => ({
  ...acc, [key]: items[key]() 
}), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible, but I don't see why `List.fold_left` should be a requirement. [`Js.Dict.map`](https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/api/Js.Dict.html#VALmap) is much more appropriate:

```
let items = Js.Dict.fromList([
  ("foo", () => "ok"),
  ("bar", () => "ok2")
]);

let result = items |> Js.Dict.map([@bs] f => f());
```